# How to describe a line and find area of a region using a spesific substitution for double integral?

Tags: integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus

My task is this;

Given coordinate change: $x = u\cos(v), \enspace y = 2u\sin(v)$.

1. Describe the line $y = 2x$ in terms of $u,v$.
2. Let $R$ be the region in the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane bounded by the $x$-axis, $y = 2x$ and $x^2 + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$. Find the area of R.

My work so far:

In terms of coordinates one could describe the line as:
$(u\cos(v),\: 2u\sin(v))$ or simply $y = 2x \to 2u\sin(v) = 2u\cos(v)$, (Not sure if this is what they want).

For the region $R$ we have that $x^2 + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1 \to y^2 = 4 - 4x^2 \to y = 2\sqrt{1 - x^2}$, since we are in the first quadrant. Then we have that $2x = 2\sqrt{1 - x^2} \to x^2 = 1 - x^2 \to x = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

After this i'm sort of lost. I don't quite know where to go fom here and tbh i'm not sure if this is the right procedure. Please don't find the area as i would like to find it myself. Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Substituting for $x$ and $y$ in $y=2x$ yields:
   $$
   2u\sin v=2u\cos v\quad \Rightarrow \quad v=\frac{\pi}{4}
   $$
   So $y=2x$ is a horizontal line in the $uv$ plane.
2. The area of $R$ is given by $A=\iint_RdA$, and given the nature of $R$ you need to describe it in terms of $u$ and $v$. You have already done half the work in (1.). For the rest, $x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ is $u=1$. It follows that 
   $$
   A=\iint_RdA = \int_{u=0}^{1}\int_{v=0}^{\pi/4}2u \;dvdu=\frac{\pi}{4}
   $$

**Note.** In terms of $x$ and $y$, the area  equals
$$
\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{y/2}^{\sqrt{1-y^2/4}}dxdy = \frac{\pi}{4},
$$
but computing the integral is not as straightforward…hence the change of variables!